# Inflate an xml file or create new intance of View in loop?

Tags: android, inflate

I am creating a screen/xml which has:

1. TextView (Header)
2. LinearLayout (placeholder to contain numerous RelativeLayouts)

I need to add many `RelativeLayout` (containing two `TextView`s) to the `LinearLayout` (mentioned above) in loop. This basically would be list of `RelativeLayouts`. I have two ways doing this:

1. Create an xml file which has the `RelativeLayout` (and two `TextViews` under it). Inflate this in the code again and again( in loop).And then add this to `LinearLayout` mentioned above.
2. Create the instance of `RelativeLayout` and `TextView` using the keyword "new". And add the instances to the above mentioned `LinearLayout`.

Which is the least expensive way.

Answer (score 1):

You should go with #1 approach - inflate layout from xml file. That's because its better to keep your code separate from your UI. You can preview and redesign your xml much easier using ADT tools, you can reuse this xml later for similar purposes and so on.

While code that creates UI is hard to read and hard to maintain, and its hard to design a proper UI using code only.

In general, its better to keep as much UI related stuff in xmls/resources. And fall back to code when its easier to use code (like creating 10 buttons with same text) or the only way to go (like dynamically generating some views).

Comment: Numerous?? Well, in that case, a list view would be more efficient.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your comment. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: This can be done with a list view as well. 1. TextView 2. ListView

Comment: Well, yes, he can add items to `ListView` instead of `LinearLayout`. But that was not the question. He asked what is better - inflate layout from xml or create `RelativeLayout` in code.

Comment: Hmmm. Well in that case, View creation itself takes a lot of time and resources. If you add to that inflating a layout everytime, I think 2nd option would be better. But, anyway, I would still suggest him to use a ListView here.

Comment: What do you mean by "every time"? From what I understood he wants to create layout once in his `onCreate`. Also I'd say there is not enough context information to judge weather `ListView` is better or not.

Comment: Well, as mentioned, "Many" relative layouts, and "numerous". I assumed that he doesn't mean 5 or 6 or 7.